# Can we stop the close-voting?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, specific-question, closed-questions

Why are people closing (er... fine, *fine*... *"putting on hold"*) questions like this one?

[How do called functions return to their caller, after being called?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17514774)

It has decent spelling and grammar, it's well-tagged, it's understandable, it's quite insightful (it shows the OP is actually thinking about what's happening), and it's 100% programming-related.
(In fact, I can't think of a more programming-related question.)

Why are people closing questions like this one? Could we stop closing everything just because we can?

Comment: Voted reopen. The question looks fine to me.

Comment: I voted to reopen as well.  This sort of question is what we should be encouraging, not shunning.

Comment: I don't think the grammar was perfect, but I agree with you about everything else.

Comment: Delete all the comments! Just a note: I left the one that I felt explained why it isn't off-topic the best, and also left the helpful non-off-topicness-related comment that got buried under all the off-topicness business.

Comment: **Yes, we can.** (Couldnt stop myself)

Comment: Thanks all, that's much better. :)

Answer (score 7):

It's been reopened now. After a little bit of editing by Lance Roberts and myself, it's a perfectly fine question.

However, I think this is a very rare case. How many times have you seen a good question like this get <s>closed</s> uhh.. *on holded*? I've only seen two or three.

There are two possible explanations.

1. **Grammar**. It's a great question, but it was hiding behind a veil of grammar errors. It took a little bit of cleaning up for me to tell what was being asked. Not a huge deal, but it does lower the question that much more in the sight of the reviewers.
2. **Close-vote piling**. Used to indicate the circumstance where new 3k users see the `close (1)` button and think, '*Hey! Someone else thought that needed closing! I'll help*' In this way, a good question can be closed with really only one misplaced vote. **Not likely** here because all the closers involved had over 10k rep. Scary... but stuff does happen.

Comment: I propose a solution: don't show the number of close-votes until the user *actually clicks* Close, or something like that. (They don't have to vote to see it, but they don't have to see it without asking to, either.) Would that prevent these cases? Maybe I should put a feature request...

Comment: Oh, and as for how many questions like this I've seen, there have been a few recently, but I'm having trouble finding them. The general trend is that people seem to love closing questions, and it seems like the "on hold" business didn't actually fix it.

Comment: Just added a feature request: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/187800

Comment: I prefer the term "crushed" for "on holdified." It makes the accomplishment sound significant.

Comment: [The close vote queue also had something to do with this.](http://stackoverflow.com/review/close/2459101) There have been a number of good questions closed as a result of the queue, because it's far easier for people to remove things from that by voting to close than voting to leave them open.