# Don't show the number of close votes unless the user requests to see it

Tags: feature-request, vote-to-close

Here's a proposal that emerged from [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/187793/154726):

People seem to **love** to vote to close, and the fact is that existing close votes tend to encourage more.

To avoid systematic bias toward closing questions, I would like to propose that the number of pending close votes *not* be displayed **unless** the user has clicked `close` (or taken a similar action).

There is really no reason to make the number of close votes on a question so obvious.

All it does is encourage users to close the question, which is:

- Useless for poor questions (because they would've been closed anyway)
- Counterpoductive for good questions
  ...since a user who would not have otherwise thought of closing the question is now explicitly encouraged to vote to close: it's basically saying, *"others think this question sucks; do you agree?"*

The same should probably be done for `delete`.

However, I think `reopen` should still display the number of required votes, because it will encourage users to read questions that may have been improved and vote to re-open them.
We're not really having problems with too many undeserving questions getting re-opened, so it should stay as-is.

Thoughts?

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd: Uh, no, this isn't a duplicate of the one you posted. Actually read my post, **carefully**. I'm not asking it to be hidden completely; I'm asking it to be visible, but hidden behind a click of some sort.

Comment: In fact, this question itself is an excellent example of people jumping to close a question without actually reading it.

Comment: Visible close votes perform a function similar to down votes. They act as markers for future readers about the quality of the post. Also, if a question is similar to another question to such an extent that a reading is not enough to differentiate between the two, then it also means that there are problems with the post and that differences need to be highlighted. If you read the close message, in case of duplicates, it says exactly this. And If the question is borderline off-topic, then it is the responsibility of the OP (to an extent) to show how the question is fit for the site.

Comment: *"Visible close votes perform a function similar to down votes."* -- I have two comments to that: (1) Downvotes are already there, we don't need something to simulate them. (2) Users don't see the number of downvotes either, unless they *actually click* the number. Same thing I'm asking for here.

Comment: @Mehrdad the answer given in your other question fits perfectly for this one as well, in my opinion.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd: It doesn't. That one says *"the ability to see how many (and what types of) close votes have already been cast is important"*, and my proposal here completely agrees with that. Nothing about that answer goes against the proposal here. Again, take a look at downvoting: it's the same kind of scenario; it's important, but we don't show the number of downvotes by default.

Comment: @Mehrdad sometimes the question is not _bad_, just _offtopic_. A downvote may not be warranted in such a case. I don't want to start answering something just to find out later I can't post the answer because I misjudged the community of closers.

Comment: @JanDvorak: If you don't want to start answering it and suspect it has close votes then can't you just click `close` and see how many votes it has? Alternatively, maybe the site could give you a notification automatically if the question is closed, so you don't keep typing.

Comment: @JanDvorak: Then again, if the question is off-topic, it might be better to answer it on the site it's migrated to, not here. Heck, if it's migrated, StackOverflow could just post the answer that you were in the middle of typing on the other site! Even better.

Comment: @Mehrdad if the question is closed for reasons unbeforeseen seconds before I try to post the solution I've spent some time writing, it's still kinda bad. While there is a certain grace period, most people don't know about it, and will ragequit instead

Comment: note that most offtopic questions don't get migrated, and I even got a declined flag trying to suggest a migration of one I thought decent (which I also answered before it was closed)

Comment: @JanDvorak: Huh? That doesn't make any sense. How does showing the number of close votes *"seconds before you try to post the solution"* help you? You've already started typing, you'll have the same problem as before even if the close votes are shown. If you *haven't* started typing, then you could just as well click "close" to see the number of close votes *before* you start typing. Same outcome either way.

Comment: @Mehrdad the difference is that I won't be looking if I don't suspect a closevote.

Comment: @JanDvorak: You won't be noticing the comments either, which would make it obvious that the post is getting closed? Or is it just the laziness to click `close` that's the problem?

Comment: @Mehrdad closers don't always comment. Not even in cases when they vote where I would never expect them to. Note this already affects low-rep users. I can feel that heavily when considering whether to answer on [programmers.se].

Comment: @JanDvorak: So you're saying *if* the question is *off-topic* **and** it doesn't get migrated somewhere else **and** no one is commenting and making it obvious that the question is getting closed **and** you think the question is *good enough to answer* **and** you haven't clicked `close` to check **and** others suddenly close the question *while* you're writing your answer, *then* the time you've spent on your answer would be wasted? Do you really think the time wasted there is more of a problem than the time OPs spend on writing legitimate questions that get closed with a couple of clicks?

Comment: Please note I haven't voted for  your suggestion. I'm just pointing out a potential issue.

Comment: Close votes attract other close votes because of close review queue, not because of people randomly browsing the questions in search for those with close votes on.

Comment: but, _if_ your suggestion actually _does_ reduce the amount of incorrect closures (which I'm far from sure), _then_ I agree it outweighs this "problem" of percieved wasted effort.

Comment: @ŁukaszLech: Ah, if you think that's the case then please post it as an answer!

Comment: Why was this closed as a duplicate?? Sigh.

Comment: this question went from no votes to closed in just about the time it took me to write an answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17539977/how-to-trigger-an-function-when-the-position-of-the-component-changed-using-jqu/17541802#17541802

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd I agree with Mehrdad - this is *not* a duplicate of the supposed duplicate question. It's very similar, but the arguments presented in the answers are invalid in many cases because this feature request intends to make the close-vote information available (albeit slightly hidden).

Comment: @Duncan feel free to flag for reopening, I still believe the answer given there also fits here. Five ordinary users or one moderator can reopen this question and I won't fight it.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd: WTF, let me get this straight -- you want Duncan to *re-open* this question that was marked as a duplicate (but isn't actually one) *just so* you can paste the *same answer* that was given to the "duplicate" on here too?! What the heck are you thinking?? This is madness...

Comment: @DuncanJones: Thanks. I'm debating deleting this question entirely, it's apparent that Sha Wiz Dow Ard and other StackOverflow'ers didn't actually read it.

Comment: @Mehrdad no, I said that if Duncan think it's not a dupe he's free to flag for reopening (or cast a reopen vote if having enough rep). Never said I'm going to post any answer.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd: Uh, you just said *"feel free to flag for reopening"* because you *"still believe the answer given there also fits here"*. Correct me if I'm wrong, but doesn't that obviously mean you just want to put the same answer here? Either I don't know English and you just put two completely irrelevant sentences next to each other and confused me, or you're contradicting yourself.

Comment: @JanDvorak: And yet you still wrote up and posted the entire answer. :) AKA seeing the close votes accumulating didn't change anything...?

Comment: @Mehrdad there were no close votes when I started writing. If there were, I may not have started writing the answer.

Comment: @JanDvorak: lol what? I thought that's what I told you earlier -- if you don't see any votes when you start then my proposal doesn't change anything. I'm not sure what your example is demonstrating then... the fact that questions get closed, or the fact that you post answers?

Comment: Trying with picture. See [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/098np.png). That's what I mean.

Comment: I have to say that I agree for `close` but not for `delete`.  There's a big difference between a 3k user and a 10k user in terms of how careful they're likely to be about me-too'ing a vote (of any sort).

Comment: Bumping this because I just had the same exact thought.

Comment: in the same vein, don't show an answerer's ***score***, unless a user requests it (by hovering or someth).

Comment: @WillNess: The *answerer*'s score? Like you mean their total reputation in the badge on an answer? I feel like if this is important at all, it'd be far more important for questions than answers?

Comment: @Mehrdad yes. people are influenced by it, often unduly, I thought. Qs or As, I havent thought about that specifically. maybe always (i.e. both).

Answer (score 4):

Agreed completely (a year later).  I've noticed that if a question has three or four close votes already, people (including myself) readily supply the last couple of votes because of the following mentality: "Well, if a bunch of other people think this question should be closed, I guess it should be."

This is the same logic for bandwagon upvoting and downvoting.  "Well this question has 42 upvotes, so it must be awesome.  I'll upvote it, too."  Or, "this question has a score of -7, it must suck.  Let's downvote it into the dirt.  Death to the OP!"

Removing the close vote count encourages people to only cast a close vote because they *actually think the question should be closed* rather than following any kind of bandwagon.

---

As a side note, this question is an example of the "related questions" feature working.  I was typing up a new question to address this exact concern and found this year-old post.  Well played!

Comment: Glad someone else is observing the same thing. Can we somehow make people revisit this proposal? It's been 3 years...

Answer (score 4):

Having your question closed is frustrating.  Having it closed erroneously and then trying to get it reopened is also frustrating.  As a result, when I see "close (N)" on a question that I *don't* think is close-worthy, I tend to comment -- asking "why does this have close votes?" if there are no comments about it, or responding to those comments if no one else has.  As a 3k user I see *preventing bad closures* as as much part of my job as *closing bad questions*.

But that'll never happen if I have to ask about pending votes on every question.  This works at all because it's *passive information*.

I don't know how many other users behave that way, but I've seen it from others (I learned this somewhere; I didn't make it up) and it's a pattern I try to spread.  **Preventing a bad closure is better than cleaning up after it,** and this proposal breaks prevention.

Comment: Disagree completely.  This entire idea is to do exactly what you say: *prevent* bad closures by people bandwagoning just because they see other people voted for it.  Your answer makes sense given an idealistic view of human nature, but I think the people who behave as you describe are much more rare than the ones who just hop on the close train.

Comment: Do you have evidence, or is that just your impression?  This would require an A/B test to really know, but interesting cases include "wrongly closed due to bandwagon" *and* "wrongly left open because prompting close votes turns out to matter".  I've seen a lot of close votes age away on questions that should have been closed.  This probably depends a lot on the size and culture of individual sites.  We don't know how rare inappropriate bandwagoning *or* intervention (like what I described) is.

Comment: True.  I'll give you that.  No definitive data either way.  Both are impressions.

Answer (score 0):

I agree that this might stop the landslide effect, but for informational purposes you still need to keep the mouseover that tells how many votes are left to close or delete.

Comment: Why would you need to keep it?

Comment: @JanDvorak, I use it to determine how close a question is getting (usually for deletion) in case it is being deleted inappropriately and needs some help.